# FollowHyperLink Run-time Error 94

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I have a listbox in which the last field is a path to a file. It's data Type is Text. I'm trying to use the following to be able to open the path:

```
Private Sub DataView_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
FollowHyperlink DataView.Column(8, DataView.ListIndex)
End Sub
```

I'm getting Run-Time error 94: Invalid use of Null.

I have this code,

```
Private Sub List36_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
FollowHyperlink List36.Column(1, List36.ListIndex)
End Sub
```

On the same form, and it works just fine, which is why I'm so confused.

I'm assuming there's some simple property that I have to change, but I can't find it. Any help would be great.

Comment: I would start by setting a break point on the line that generates the error and evaluate what you are passing the FollowHypterlink method in a valid and invalid case.

Comment: I was just using the debugger wrong before.

Counting starts at 0, not 1...
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Counting starts at 0, not 1. I was indexing out of bounds